# Replace "not right now" label to "dismiss" for the new profile features notification

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, wording

When I went to my profile page today I saw the notification for new fields that can be filled in my profile, with a button at the corner reading "not right now". Clicking on it shows a message saying that this notification will not show up again and now I might never know what I missed.

Comment: You can't really "miss" anything. You'll still see them whenever you go edit your profile again. The "not right now" text is meant as a "I will go edit my profile some other time."